# difference in execution turbo and visual

Tags: c, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Consider, following 2 coding lines in C

```
int a=0;

printf("%d%d%d%d",++a,a+1,a++,++a);
```

in visual C++, it gives

> output:3431

But in Turbo C++
gives:

> output:3311

This is also compiler dependent?

Comment: Order of evaluation in the absence of sequence points is [unspecified behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior).

Comment: This is answered by an entry of the [C++ SO FAQ](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#toc11)

Comment: @Mat isn't `,` a sequence point?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore only as the comma operator, not as the separator of function arguments.

Comment: @DanielFischer there's a difference? whoa... mind=blown

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Nor as the separator for variable declarations, by the way. Yes, there's a difference between these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C specification does not specify the order that the arguments to your function will be evaluated, so there's no guarantee what output you will get.

Comment: It's not just that the output isn't guaranteed. He's modified `a` more than once between sequence points, which leads to undefined behavior. Therefore it's not just a matter of "could be 3 or 4", but could also include "formats the hard disk", "blows up the machine", or essentially anything else.